# I want to fetch students data, but it only fetches a single line of data

Tags: codeigniter

I'm developing a student information system, and I'm stuck in this problem. Whenever I fetch the student data, it only returns a single row of data.
Can you help me? How to fix this problem? Thank you

**controller**

```php
function  Account_Validation() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="text-danger">', '</p>');

    if($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
        $this -> load -> view ('login');
    } else {
        $username = $this -> input -> post('Username');
        $password = md5($this -> input -> post('Password'));

        $check = $this -> Model_login -> login($username, $password);   

        if($check) {

            foreach($check as $row);   

            $data = array (   
                 'User_id' =>  $row -> User_id,   
                 'Confirm_password' =>  $row -> Confirm_password,   
                 'sectioning_id' =>  $row -> sectioning_id,   
                 'default_section_id' =>  $row -> default_section_id,   
                 'default_section' =>  $row -> default_section,   
                 'yeargrade_id' =>  $row -> yeargrade_id,
                 'Username' => $row -> Username,
                 'status' => $row -> status,
                 'Level' => $row -> Level, 
                 'first_name' => $row -> first_name,
                 'middle_name' => $row -> middle_name,
                 'last_name' => $row -> last_name,   
                 'programs' => $row -> programs,   
                 'userfile' => $row -> userfile,
             );

            $this -> session -> set_userdata($data);     

            if($this -> session -> userdata('Level') == "1") {

                $this -> session -> set_flashdata('Success',  "You've Successfuly Logged In");   
                redirect('Admin/Dashboard');

            } elseif ($this -> session -> userdata('Level') == "2") {

                $this -> session -> set_flashdata('Success',  'Successfuly Logged In'); 
                redirect('Registrar/Dashboard');    
            }

        } else {
            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('error',  'Invalid Username/Password Combination');
            redirect('login');  
        }            
    }
}
```

**Model**

```php
function login($username, $password) {

    $this -> db -> select('a.User_id, a.Username, a.Password, a.userfile, a.status, a.Level, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.last_name, b.default_section_id, c.default_section, d.yeargrade_id, e.subject, a.Confirm_password');
    $this -> db -> from('user_tbl a');
    $this -> db -> join ('sectioning_tbl b', 'a.User_id = b.User_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> join ('default_section_tbl c', 'b.default_section_id = c.default_section_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> join ('studentyeartbl d', 'd.yeargrade_id = c.default_section_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> join ('default_subject_tbl e', 'e.yeargrade_id = c.yeargrade_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> where ('Username', $username);
    $this -> db -> where ('Password', $password);
    $result = $this -> db -> get ();
    $this -> db -> limit (1);
    return $result -> result();
}
```

Comment: So... you want to get data of all the students in `login` and/or `Account_Validation` function? That makes no sense... Instead of copying the same sentence to satisfy text length requirements, describe your issue properly

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove this line from your model:
`$this -> db -> limit (1);`

That funciton on codeigniter puts `LIMIT 1` in the query, so you'll only get one row. 
On the other side, if that's a login, makes sense you only fetch one row. And your controller seems to have logic to handle several rows, but will redirect on the first match of username and password so if you have several users with the same login, maybe you'll give access to the wrong user.

Maybe this will work.
- Model

```
function login($username, $password) {

    $this -> db -> select('a.User_id, a.Username, a.Password, a.userfile, a.status, a.Level, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.last_name, b.default_section_id, c.default_section, d.yeargrade_id, e.subject, a.Confirm_password');
    $this -> db -> from('user_tbl a');
    $this -> db -> join ('sectioning_tbl b', 'a.User_id = b.User_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> join ('default_section_tbl c', 'b.default_section_id = c.default_section_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> join ('studentyeartbl d', 'd.yeargrade_id = c.default_section_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> join ('default_subject_tbl e', 'e.yeargrade_id = c.yeargrade_id', 'left');
    $this -> db -> where ('Username', $username);
    $this -> db -> where ('Password', $password);
    $result = $this -> db -> get ();
    $result =  $result -> result();
    return ( isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : FALSE);
}
```

- Controller

```
function  Account_Validation() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="text-danger">', '</p>');

    if($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {

        $this -> load -> view ('login');

    } else {

        $username = $this -> input -> post('Username');
        $password = md5($this -> input -> post('Password'));

        $row = $this -> Model_login -> login($username, $password);   



        if($row) {

         $data = array (   
         'User_id' =>  $row -> User_id,   
         'Confirm_password' =>  $row -> Confirm_password,   
         'sectioning_id' =>  $row -> sectioning_id,   
         'default_section_id' =>  $row -> default_section_id,   
         'default_section' =>  $row -> default_section,   
         'yeargrade_id' =>  $row -> yeargrade_id,
         'Username' => $row -> Username,
         'status' => $row -> status,
         'Level' => $row -> Level, 
         'first_name' => $row -> first_name,
         'middle_name' => $row -> middle_name,
         'last_name' => $row -> last_name,   
         'programs' => $row -> programs,   
         'userfile' => $row -> userfile,     

         );

        $this -> session -> set_userdata($data);     

        if($this -> session -> userdata('Level') == "1") {

            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('Success',  "You've Successfuly Logged In");   
            redirect('Admin/Dashboard');

        } elseif ($this -> session -> userdata('Level') == "2") {

            $this -> session -> set_flashdata('Success',  'Successfuly Logged In'); 
            redirect('Registrar/Dashboard');

        }

      } else {
          $this -> session -> set_flashdata('error',  'Invalid Username/Password Combination');
            redirect('login');  
    }


}
```